# Jumping to a div on a different page with a fixed header

Tags: html

From one page I am linking to a certain section of another page:

```
<a href="page.html#section">link</a>
```

On page.html:

```
<div id="section">
jumping here
</div>
```

The page I am jumping to has a fixed header, and the top of the #section div is getting obstructed by the header when I jump to it. How can I prevent that?

I have seen plenty of topics about how to adjust an anchor within the same page to solve this problem, but not how to jump to a div from another page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by adding a new element to your div, and position it above it.

```
<div>
    <a id="section" style="margin-top: -50px;"></a>
    jumping here
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <a id="section" style="position: absolute; top: -50px;"></a>
    jumping here
</div>
```

Hope it helps you out!